# Unable to set email notification from MWAA

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am trying to set Email notification from MWAA. I did all settings in Airflow configuration options - optional (AWS console). But my email notification stage is failing with following errors in logs

===========================error=========================

```
[2022-05-30, 10:04:46 UTC] {{email.py:208}} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 1
[2022-05-30, 10:05:16 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1703}} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1332, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1458, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, self.task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1514, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/email.py", line 88, in execute
    conn_id=self.conn_id,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 66, in send_email
    **kwargs,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 102, in send_email_smtp
    send_mime_email(e_from=smtp_mail_from, e_to=recipients, mime_msg=msg, conn_id=conn_id, dryrun=dryrun)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 210, in send_mime_email
    conn = _get_smtp_connection(smtp_host, smtp_port, smtp_timeout, smtp_ssl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 244, in _get_smtp_connection
    else smtplib.SMTP(host=host, port=port, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 728, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```